# Jump speed increasing I don't know why Libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm creating a 2D game. I have a character which can move LEFT, RIGHT and JUMP. But every jump is faster and I donat know why.

When I start the game first, the jump is OK. But every next jump is faster. I think something is increasing the speed but I don't know what.

Can someone look into my code?

Here is my MainCharacter class:

```
public class MainCharacter {
    private static final int GRAVITY = -5;
    private static final int MOVEMENT = 5;

    private Vector3 position;
    private Vector3 velocity;

    private Texture character;

    public MainCharacter(int x, int y){
        position = new Vector3(x,y,0);
        velocity = new Vector3(0,0,0);
        character = new Texture("character.png");
    }

    public void update(float dt)
    {
        if(position.y>50)
            velocity.add(0,GRAVITY,0);
        velocity.scl(dt);
        position.add(0,velocity.y,0);
        if(position.y<=50)
            position.y=50;
        velocity.scl(1/dt);
    }

    public void moveLeft(){position.x=(position.x-MOVEMENT);}

    public void moveRight(){position.x=(position.x+MOVEMENT);}

    public void jump(){
        if(position.y==50){
            position.y=150;
        }

    }
    public Vector3 getPosition(){ return position; }

    public Texture getTexture(){ return character; }
}
```

And this is my PlayState:

```
public class PlayState extends State {

    private Texture bg;
    private MainCharacter character;

    public PlayState(GameStateManager gsm){
        super(gsm);
        bg = new Texture("bg.png");
        character = new MainCharacter(500,50);
        cam.setToOrtho(false,State.WIDTH,State.HEIGHT);
    }

    @Override
    protected void handleInput() {
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
            if (Gdx.input.isTouched(i)) {

                int x = Gdx.input.getX(i);
                int y = Gdx.input.getY(i);
                if (x < State.WIDTH / 2 && y > State.HEIGHT / 2) {
                    character.moveLeft();
                } else if (x >= State.WIDTH / 2 && y > State.HEIGHT / 2) {
                    character.moveRight();
                } else if (x < State.WIDTH / 2 && y < State.HEIGHT / 2) {
                    character.jump();
                }

            }
        }

    }


    @Override
    protected void update(float dt) {
        handleInput();
        character.update(dt);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(SpriteBatch sb) {
        sb.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
        sb.begin();
        sb.draw(bg,0,0);
        sb.draw(character.getTexture(), character.getPosition().x,character.getPosition().y);
        sb.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your update method, you add something to the current velocity, and then scale the new current velocity by dt. So you are scaling your velocity by dt repeatedly, which doesn't make sense.

If you imagine doing this with some arbitrary units, it's like this:

```
if(position.y>50)
    velocity.add(0,GRAVITY,0); // Velocity is 120 m/s. Add -1 m/s to it (regardless 
                               // of how much time has passed since last frame!) so now 
                               // it is 119 m/s.
velocity.scl(dt); // Scale the velocity by the time passed since last frame, probably 
                  // about 1/60 s, so now the velocity is 119/60 = 1.98 m/s.
```

Now on the next frame, about a 60th of a second later you do it again:

```
if(position.y>50)
    velocity.add(0,GRAVITY,0); // Velocity is 1.98 m/s. Add -1 m/s to it so now it's 0.98m/s.
velocity.scl(dt); // Scale by dt (about 1/60 s), so now the velocity is 0.98/60 = 0.0163 m/s.
```

This example will rapidly shrink to zero, but it could grow instead with different units.

You need to be thinking about acceleration in terms of units per second squared, and multiply it by dt before adding it to velocity. And you should not scale the actual velocity that you store in a variable before adding it to position.  Your update method should look like this:

```
public void update(float dt)
    {
        if(position.y > 50)
            velocity.add(0, GRAVITY * dt, 0);
        position.add(0, velocity.y * dt, 0);
        if(position.y <= 50)
            position.y = 50;
    }
```

You're movement also needs to be based on multiplying a velocity (your `MOVEMENT` variable) by dt, so really your input controller should tell your character class whether it should currently be moving left, right, or not at all. You can do this by passing it a variable direction of -1, 1, or zero (whenever not touching input) that it stores in a member variable `direction`. Then in the character's update method, you can update the position with:

```
position.x += direction * MOVEMENT * dt;
```

Also, it's kind of weird to be using integer units for gravity and movement velocity. You're going to want the precision of floats to be able to tweak those values into something that feels good.